# Sort array with accents - PHP (French)

Tags: php, sorting, utf-8

I want to sort a table with accents
Array:

```
0   Aucaleuc
1   Bobital
2   Broons
3   Brusvily
4   Calorguen
5   Caulnes
6   Dinan
7   Dinan-Hôpital
8   Dinan-Saint-Malo
9   Guenroc
10  Évran
```

But the last elements **Évran** must be after **Dinan-Saint-Malo** !

I tried that:

```
//Sort by 'ASC' with ACCENTS
setLocale(LC_COLLATE, 'fr_FR.utf8');
sort($communes);
//asort($communes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had also tried the Collator Object but it was not working because with symfony it necessary to install INTL Component with next command:

```
 composer require symfony/intl
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html

Then in PHP (for my case), I've make that:

```
$coll = collator_create( 'fr_FR' );
collator_sort( $coll, $communes );
```

Thanks !